# nunit-console.exe hangs after a few hundred tests

Tags: nunit

please help me:

I run nunit in in the windows console.

After more than 300 tests the programm hangs. I don't konw why.

```
C:\Projekte\Sochi2014_TP_testing\reporting>"NUnit 2.6"\bin\nunit-console.exe /la
bels /out=NUnitTestResult.txt /xml=NUnitTestResult.xml ..\bin\x86\Debug\Sochi201
4_TP_testing.dll
NUnit-Console version 2.6.0.12051
Copyright (C) 2002-20011 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5456 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
Log4Net not configured. Looked for file: C:\Projekte\Sochi2014_TP_testing\bin\x8
6\Debug\log4net.config
```

**More details for my issue:**

I use selenium and specflow.
Nunit hangs up in a "Scenario Outline". The previous test runs normal. The browser (FF 13) is open and runs normal when I use the mouse.

Comment: no reaction since more than 3 hours

Answer (score 3):

My *guess* is that you have a test with a deadlock. You can add a timeout to NUnit:

```
nunit-console /timeout=10000 (other options as before)
```

This adds a 10 second timeout to each test. Then you should be able to see which test times out, and work out where the problem is. The number of tests shouldn't be an issue - my Noda Time project has thousands of tests which run without a problem, and I'm sure that's far from the biggest project using NUnit...

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Do I understand it right: If the test hasn't finished after 10 second, nunit stops the test and move to the next test?

Comment: If you add `/labels` to the command line, you will see an output as each test is executed.  (I forget if it is before or after the test.)

Comment: @user1811476: Yes, I believe it will hard-abort the test.